# Pandas: Replace text of entire cell using regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called 'qualification'.
It has values like:

```
b.tech                           
graduate                         
btech                             
hsc                               
degree                            
12th pass                         
pharm.d 2nd year                  
b pharm                           
pursuing b pharm                  
ssc                               
b.pharm                           
mba                               
bsc                               
no                                
student                           
pharm.d 3rd year                  
b.com                             
bcom                              
ug                                
diploma                           
b tech
```

I want to make the data consistent by replacing certain values with other text.
For instance,
`b tech` or `b.tech` or `bachelors in X` becomes `Graduate`. Or `Masters`, `M.Com`, etc with `Post Graduate`. 
How do I do that using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
to_replace = [r'SearchRegEx1', r'SearchRegEx2', ...]
value = [r'ReplaceRegEx1', r'ReplaceRegEx2', ...]
```

and then

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].replace(to_replace, value, regex=True)
```

**Demo:**

```
In [124]: to_replace = [r'btech|b[\.\s]+\w+|bachelors\b.*', r'Masters|M.Com']
     ...: value = ['Graduate', 'Post Graduate']
     ...:

In [125]: df['col'] = df['col'].replace(to_replace, value, regex=True)

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
         col
0   Graduate
1   graduate
2   Graduate
3        hsc
4     degree
5       12th
6    pharm.d
7          b
8   pursuing
9        ssc
10  Graduate
11       mba
12       bsc
13        no
14   student
15   pharm.d
16  Graduate
17      bcom
18        ug
19   diploma
20         b
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out.